# How to deploy Incremental Static Regeneration in firebase?

Tags: firebase, next.js

How to deploy ISR build folder in next js to firebase? I migrate from ssg to isr, currently, I deploy the out folder with export method. Now when I remove (export method (does not support ISR (getStatichPath fallback: true right?) firebase can't detect the index folder...

Any tutorial? How to deploy nextjs with Incremental Static Regeneration? ISR?

What I know is firebase deploy from out folder (SSG)

Firebase settings:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "public": "out/",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) is working out of the box with firebase even with a revalidate option.
Make sure to follow the guidelines for the [firebase/nextjs setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/nextjs).

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const props: Props = {
    updatedAt: new Date().getTime(),
  };
  return {
    props: props,
    revalidate: 10, // number of seconds to regenerate the page
  };
};
```

Once deployed (`yarn deploy`), data will be updated every 10 seconds